# Loop Splitting makes code slower

Tags: c, performance, optimization

So I'm optimizing a loop (as homework) that adds 10,000 elements 600,000 times. The time without optimizations is 23.34s~ and my goal is to reach less than 7 seconds for a B and less than 5 for an A.

So I started my optimizations by first unrolling the loop like this.

```
int     j;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 8) {
            sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] +  array[j+6] + array[j+7];
```

This reduces the runtime to about 6.4~ seconds (I can hit about 6 if I unroll further).

So I figured I would try adding sub-sums and making a final sum at the end to save time on read-write dependencies and I came up with code that looks like this.

```
int     j;

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 8) {
        sum0 += array[j] + array[j+1]; 
        sum1 += array[j+2] + array[j+3];
        sum2 += array[j+4] + array[j+5]; 
        sum3 += array[j+6] + array[j+7];
```

However this **increases** the runtime to about 6.8 seconds

I tried a similar technique using pointers and the best I could do was about 15 seconds.

I only know that the machine I'm running this on (as it is a service purchased by the school) is a 32 bit, remote, Intel based, Linux virtual server that I believe is running Red Hat.

I've tried every technique I can think of to speed up the code, but they all seem to have the opposite effect. Could someone elaborate on what I'm doing wrong? Or another technique I could use to lower the runtime? The best the teacher could do was about 4.8 seconds.

As an additional condition I cannot have more than 50 lines of code in the finished project, so doing something complex is likely not possible.

Here is a full copy of both sources

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// You are only allowed to make changes to this code as specified by the comments in it.

// The code you submit must have these two values.
#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000

int main(void)
{
    double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double  sum = 0;
    int     i;

    // You can add variables between this comment ...

//  double sum0 = 0;
//  double sum1 = 0;
//  double sum2 = 0;
//  double sum3 = 0;

    // ... and this one.

    // Please change 'your name' to your actual name.
    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - ACTUAL NAME\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

        // You can change anything between this comment ...

        int     j;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 8) {
            sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] +  array[j+6] + array[j+7];
        }

        // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the same
        // number of additions as this one does.

        }

    // You can add some final code between this comment ...
//  sum = sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
    // ... and this one.

    return 0;
}
```

Broken up code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// You are only allowed to make changes to this code as specified by the comments in it.

// The code you submit must have these two values.
#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000

int main(void)
{
    double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double  sum = 0;
    int     i;

    // You can add variables between this comment ...

    double sum0 = 0;
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sum3 = 0;

    // ... and this one.

    // Please change 'your name' to your actual name.
    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - ACTUAL NAME\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

        // You can change anything between this comment ...

        int     j;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 8) {
            sum0 += array[j] + array[j+1]; 
            sum1 += array[j+2] + array[j+3];
            sum2 += array[j+4] + array[j+5]; 
            sum3 += array[j+6] + array[j+7];
        }

        // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the same
        // number of additions as this one does.

        }

    // You can add some final code between this comment ...
    sum = sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
    // ... and this one.

    return 0;
}
```

**ANSWER**

The 'time' application we use to judge the grade is a little bit off. The best I could do was 4.9~ by unrolling the loop 50 times and grouping it like I did below using TomKarzes's basic format.

```
int     j;
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 50) {
            sum +=(((((((array[j] + array[j+1]) + (array[j+2] + array[j+3])) +
                    ((array[j+4] + array[j+5]) + (array[j+6] + array[j+7]))) + 
                    (((array[j+8] + array[j+9]) + (array[j+10] + array[j+11])) +
                    ((array[j+12] + array[j+13]) + (array[j+14] + array[j+15])))) +
                    ((((array[j+16] + array[j+17]) + (array[j+18] + array[j+19]))))) +
                    (((((array[j+20] + array[j+21]) + (array[j+22] + array[j+23])) +
                    ((array[j+24] + array[j+25]) + (array[j+26] + array[j+27]))) + 
                    (((array[j+28] + array[j+29]) + (array[j+30] + array[j+31])) +
                    ((array[j+32] + array[j+33]) + (array[j+34] + array[j+35])))) +
                    ((((array[j+36] + array[j+37]) + (array[j+38] + array[j+39])))))) + 
                    ((((array[j+40] + array[j+41]) + (array[j+42] + array[j+43])) +
                    ((array[j+44] + array[j+45]) + (array[j+46] + array[j+47]))) + 
                    (array[j+48] + array[j+49])));
        }
```

Comment: What is 'B' and 'A'?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, that change if it impacts performance at all it wouldn't be so dramatic.

Comment: This could be due to the way modern CPUs optimize vector operations.

Comment: At first the second variant must be slower because you add yet one operation (save result of each sum in variable). At second if you want improve performance then use threads and processor vector operations(SIMD) like it wrote above.

Comment: @pvg, those are letter grades for the assignment based on the speed I attain.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what compiler options are you specifying?

Comment: @TomKarzes gcc -m32 -std=gnull -Wall

Comment: Try adding `-O3` to your compiler options.  That will enable more compile-time optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this is a 'manual optimizations only' assignment and I cannot enable compiler optimizations.

Comment: The point of the exercise is for you to perform the optimizations. Adding any -O just optimizes the whole thing away. This is also why the more complex code performs slightly slower - you've got a few extra stores per loop in there. You can probably check the disassembly to compare.

Comment: @pvg Even with the default optimization level, I would still expect `sum0`, `sum1`, etc. to be kept in registers, so I don't buy your argument.  The transformation that was performed makes sense and I wouldn't have expected it to make things worse as long as those variables are kept in registers.  In fact, it should reduce dependencies in the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion to add `-O3` is the only *sane* suggestion. There are a lot of optimizations you can do to code. The ones you are taught by working with a lobotomized compiler are special in that they are *entirely* worthless as soon as you let the compiler do its job. This doesn't teach you anything of value.

Comment: Does the fact you're running on a virtual server mean your timings will be unreliable? The CPU time may be stolen

Comment: @TomKarzes It doesn't seem to keep things in registers. It creates 4 empty spaces using fldz and ftstpl.

Comment: @TomKarzes I don't know why you'd expect that nor does it. It does loads and stores for each. Check the assembly output with -S

Comment: @James the time can be slower or faster depending on how the server masters feel. So the teacher wrote benchmarks to run every term and a sub 5 second result seems possible from the last time he ran it in class.

Comment: @pvg If I remove the sub sums and use one sum I do gain time but I'm back to square one in terms of optimizations.

Comment: @LegionDaeth well, I suppose one cheeky optimization is - you're asked to perform the same number of additions. It doesn't really say additions of __what__ :)

Comment: Simple solution: use a faster CPU/system. A specific time-target is useless without a fixed hardware-setup. I doubt this question is on-topic here, as the code apparently is working. It might be better on code-review.

Comment: Ok, I guess by default it's using -O0, and apparently it isn't doing register allocation for variables. Try this: Add the register keyword to the declarations of sum0, etc., i.e. `register double sum0;` That seems to be within the rules. Also add it to the declaration of `j`, i.e.  `register int j;`

Comment: You can hardly not use registers. However, hand-optimising the code is somewhat another nonsense constraint.

Comment: @pvg I think I'd get hit with the F-stick if I tried that since the instrs.txt file specifies that "your inner loop should still compute the sum of all the elements of the array". Good thinking though XD

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks again for the suggestion. Using register on modern cpus can apparently generate garbage so we are forbidden from using it.

Comment: @Olaf the schools linux server is the fixed hardware setup and is what our code needs to perform well on.

Comment: Wow, this assignment is really horrible.  They're basically forcing you to do things you should never do.  It would have made a lot more sense if they'd *required* the use of `-O3`, then said "now see if you can make some code changes to improve things further".

Comment: @TomKarzes -O3 (or even 1) fully eliminates the whole thing. You'd have to make the exercise 'force the compiler to emit code anyway, at -O3'.

Comment: @pvg Yes, but that's another problem with the assignment.  It should be forced to generate a result that requires the computation to be performed.

Comment: @LegionDaeth: Question is, how they measure the time. CPU time or simple system time? Just halting all other processes might help already :-).

Comment: Hint: force the array to be allocated at a cache-line (IIRC 64 bytes on x86). Worst cast manually align it. Too bad you're not allowed to use SSE/AVX, because that involves some kind of assembler instructions (althought they are available as intrinsics).

Comment: @Legion  Here are a couple more things you can try, starting with the original loop (with a single `sum` variable):  (1) Experiment with adding parentheses to force different groupings.  The two extremes are (a) balancing them, e.g. `((a+b)+(c+d))+((e+f)+(g+h))`, and (b) linearizing them.  Normally I would say balancing them should be better, but with optimizations disabled, who knows.  And (2) Unroll the loop one more time, using `j += 16` as the incremement and adding 16 items per iteration.  Do *not* introduce any intermediate variables.  Just use one long sum.

Comment: hang on. it says your inner loop must do the same number of additions. It doesn't say how many times you have to run the inner loop. You can just skip it after the first iteration, unless, again, your magical instructions are being a dick somewhere.

Comment: @pvg skip it after the first iteration? Wouldn't that just leave me with 8/(600,000 * 10,000) elements added together?

Comment: I meant is there anything in the conditions that requires you to actually run the inner loop for i > 0?

Comment: Because if not, it has a lot of nice properties, as a solution. First, it's emulating something a compiler would actually do (i.e. hoist loop independent code out of a loop) and second it would crush the time of your teacher's solution like a bug.

Comment: @pvg Oh I get it. So calculate the sum of 10,000 elements and multiply it by 600,000 since all operations after the first would be redundant. Hmm... In theory I could within the context of the rules set i to 599,999+ which would stop the outer loop and allow me to generate the ultimate result by multiplying by 600k. Well the rules the instrs.txt specifies are as follows.

*You should not alter the outer loop
*You should nto change the size of teh array or its data type
*The array should remain initialized to all 0's
*Your inner loop should still compute the sum of all the elements...

Comment: ..of the array
*your code should be no longer than 50 lines
*your code should not use the "register" keyword

Comment: well you can just put the inner loop in if (i < 1 ) { inner loop) or something similar. that seems within the rules, perhaps unintentionally but as far as i can read it, it is.

Comment: Here's something potentially more helpful. I'm getting pretty decent improvement by breaking up the additions in locally scoped variables and then adding them inside the loop. Give it a try. https://gist.github.com/pvg/03abe6576794be1ea8059466548413e5

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried your technique and I got the time down to 5.4 seconds. I just need one more little push!

Comment: Try the local vars and not +=ing them. I think that improves locality enough for the compiler to emit better code and you get some superscalarity benefits from the cpu too. I get another 5-10% out of that and I haven't fiddled with the numbers much.

Comment: @TomKarzes Often people do things for the sake of learning that aren't useful in the real world.

Comment: @pvg using local variables the runtime went up .5 seconds.

Comment: @pvg it seems like the overhead of having to add up the sum multiple times is causing too much of a performance loss.

Comment: Pretty consistently better than your + + + version for me, for some reason. Oh well.

Comment: Best possible with `-O0` is `register` on `i, j, sum` a static declaration of `array[ARRAY_SIZE]` and Tom's 16 element unrolling. `real 0m4.642s, user 0m4.640s,sys 0m0.000s `

Comment: Given this specific setup, you can trivially optimize out everything.

`calloc` zeroes out the memory it returns, so the entire loop just repeatedly sums `0`.

That's probably not what the teacher wants the answer to be.

Comment: @MSN It is. If you look at the comments on the full source code it should show that there is only a small specific editable area I am allowed to code in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with the grouping a bit.  On my machine, with my `gcc`, I found that the following worked best:

```
    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 16) {
        sum = sum +
              (array[j   ] + array[j+ 1]) +
              (array[j+ 2] + array[j+ 3]) +
              (array[j+ 4] + array[j+ 5]) +
              (array[j+ 6] + array[j+ 7]) +
              (array[j+ 8] + array[j+ 9]) +
              (array[j+10] + array[j+11]) +
              (array[j+12] + array[j+13]) +
              (array[j+14] + array[j+15]);
    }
```

In other words, it's unrolled 16 times, it groups the sums into pairs, and then it adds the pairs linearly.  I also removed the `+=` operator, which affects when `sum` is first used in the additions.

I found that the measured times varied significantly from one run to the next, even without changing anything, so I suggest timing each version several times before making any conclusions about whether the time has improved or gotten worse.

I'd be interested to know what numbers you get on your machine with this version of the inner loop.

Update:  Here's my current fastest version (on my machine, with my compiler):

```
    int     j1, j2;

    j1 = 0;
    do {
        j2 = j1 + 20;
        sum = sum +
              (array[j1   ] + array[j1+ 1]) +
              (array[j1+ 2] + array[j1+ 3]) +
              (array[j1+ 4] + array[j1+ 5]) +
              (array[j1+ 6] + array[j1+ 7]) +
              (array[j1+ 8] + array[j1+ 9]) +
              (array[j1+10] + array[j1+11]) +
              (array[j1+12] + array[j1+13]) +
              (array[j1+14] + array[j1+15]) +
              (array[j1+16] + array[j1+17]) +
              (array[j1+18] + array[j1+19]);
        j1 = j2 + 20;
        sum = sum +
              (array[j2   ] + array[j2+ 1]) +
              (array[j2+ 2] + array[j2+ 3]) +
              (array[j2+ 4] + array[j2+ 5]) +
              (array[j2+ 6] + array[j2+ 7]) +
              (array[j2+ 8] + array[j2+ 9]) +
              (array[j2+10] + array[j2+11]) +
              (array[j2+12] + array[j2+13]) +
              (array[j2+14] + array[j2+15]) +
              (array[j2+16] + array[j2+17]) +
              (array[j2+18] + array[j2+19]);
    }
    while (j1 < ARRAY_SIZE);
```

This uses a total unroll amount of 40, split into two groups of 20, with alternating induction variables that are pre-incremenented to break dependencies, and a post-tested loop.  Again, you can experiment with the parentheses groupings to fine-tune it for your compiler and platform.

Comment: I ran your code (along with versions using different groupings) and got about 5.5 seconds on average for every version (including that one) tested. My current version which unrolls to 20, and groups them all with their neighbors like that then with their neighbors again and again until one operation is left gets to about 5.4-5.1.

Comment: It sounds like you're close to squeezing as much out of it as you can.  The unroll amount of 20 is interesting.  Normally I think of unrolling by powers of two, but in this case there's really no reason not to unroll by other amounts that are factors of the total trip count.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what what your teacher did that reliably gets them to under 5 which you can't seem to reach despite all the fiddling. It almost seems like we're guessing around the codegen of slightly different versions of gcc on slightly different platforms.

Comment: I have a new loop unrolling which seems to make a significant difference.  I've updated my post to include it.  Please take a look at the new loop at the bottom of my post.  I suggest trying it out, then experiment with adding parentheses to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with the following approaches:

- No optimization, for loop with integer indexes by 1, simple `sum +=`. This took 16.4 seconds on my **64 bit** 2011 MacBook Pro.
- gcc -O2, same code, got down to 5.46 seconds.
- gcc -O3, same code, got down to 5.45 seconds.
- I tried using your code with 8-way addition into the sum variable. This took it down to 2.03 seconds.
- I doubled that to 16-way additon into the sum variable, this took it down to 1.91 seconds.
- I doubled that to 32-way addition into the sum variable. The time WENT UP to 2.08 seconds.
- I switched to a pointer approach, as suggested by @kcraigie. With -O3, the time was 6.01 seconds. (Very surprising to me!)

  ```
  register double * p;
  for (p = array; p < array + ARRAY_SIZE; ++p) {
      sum += *p;
  }
  ```
- I changed the for loop to a while loop, with `sum += *p++` and got the time down to 5.64 seconds.
- I changed the while loop to count down instead of up, the time went up to 5.88 seconds.
- I changed back to a for loop with incrementing-by-8 integer index, added 8 register double sum[0-7] variables, and added _array[j+N] to sumN for N in [0,7]. With `_array` declared to be a register double *const initialized to `array`, on the chance that it matters. This got the time down to 1.86 seconds.
- I changed to a macro that expanded to 10,000 copies of +_array[n], with N a constant. Then I did `sum = tnKX(addsum)` and the compiler crashed with a segmentation fault. So a pure-inlining approach isn't going to work.
- I switched to a macro that expanded to 10,000 copies of `sum += _array[n]` with N a constant. That ran in 6.63 seconds!! Apparently the overhead of loading all that code reduces the effectiveness of the inlining.
- I tried declaring a `static double _array[ARRAY_SIZE];` and then using `__builtin_memcpy` to copy it before the first loop. With the 8-way parallel addition, this resulted in a time of 2.96 seconds. I don't think static array is the way to go. (Sad - I was hoping the constant address would be a winner.)

From all this, it seems like 16-way inlining or 8-way parallel variables should be the way to go. You'll have to try this on your own platform to make sure - I don't know what the wider architecture will do to the numbers.

**Edit:**

Following a suggestion from @pvg, I added this code:

```
int ntimes = 0;

// ... and this one.
...
    // You can change anything between this comment ...

            if (ntimes++ == 0) {
```

Which reduced the run time to < 0.01 seconds. ;-) It's a winner, if you don't get hit with the F-stick.

Comment: This is a strictly -O0 assignment though, as it says in the comments.

Comment: When I started this post, that hadn't been said yet. ;-)

Comment: Testing on my end makes it seem like 16 way addition is the best possible result at the moment. I just need to push it .3~ish over into the goal zone.